# WPF ScrollViewer not working

Tags: c#, wpf

this question asked several times but none of those solution is working for me.It a simple case even though it is not working.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Pages.Animals"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pages"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
 >
<Grid>
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Height="300">
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>

    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button Content="Test"/>
    </StackPanel>

    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Someone please tell me what I am missing. Is it something related to project settings?

I even created a new usercontrol and followed this example ([this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFScrollViewer.aspx)).Even this is not working.

I am placing this user control under `Page` as `TabControl` and this Page is displayed in a `Window` as a Frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**remove the stack Height="300"** it will work;
ScrollViewer when active the chield height be more than ScrollViewer height

```
<ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel >
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Try to give your user-control with and heght

Comment: Yeah setting those is working. But I need to align it to width and height of window height and width

Comment: @djkp The sizing of the UserControl is a separate problem. Try putting the UserControl in a Grid within the Window. Show us the Window XAML if you need help with that.

Comment: so try to give it the parent with and heght